# How to export javascript from html using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to identify and get a javascript from a html page.

How can I do it using python?

I tried [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) But I couldn't find how...

Comment: There's not enough info in your question. Please edit. What do you mean 'get Javascript from a HTML page' - what HTML page, did you call/download it? What have you tried exactly? What failed how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = "page to get"
pg = requests.get(URL).content
pg = bs.BeautifulSoup(pg)

scripts = bs.findAll('script')

for sc in scripts:
    try:
        print("External code at {}".format(sc['src']))
    except KeyError:
        print("Inline code:")
        print(sc.getText())
```